# ecw file with mapserver

Tags: ecw, mapserver

I have a problem with ecw file. I'm using mapserver and openlayers. I have a ecw file and I make my tileindex file with gdaltindex. I want to put in my map file, I tried many ways but no ones work. How can I show my ecw files in my map?

PS: I have support for ecw files by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in a similar way than tileindex with geotiffs. Actually I would recommend to test first with a geotiff tileindex and couple of images so that you know that everything else despite ECW is configured correctly. If changing to ECW breaks something you know where to start searching the reason for the issue. It can be that the GDAL of your Mapserver does not support ECW. However, if you could create the tileindex then probably that is not the case. Two suggerstions:

- Perhaps the paths in tileindex are not correct? I always create them with 
  "-write_absolute_path" but some others prefer to write them relative to SHAPEPATH http://www.mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html.
- Learn to use DEBUG in your mapfiles
- Learn to test with shp2img utility, it removes the hassle caused by the clients and the web. Once you know that Mapserver is OK you can continue and try to connect it from your client.

> ```
> LAYER
> NAME 'ecw_tileindex_layer'
> TYPE RASTER
> #DEBUG 5 
> #In case of trouble uncomment DEBUG and see MS_ERRORFILE
> TILEINDEX 'users/user/data/ecw_tileindex.shp'
> STATUS ON
> OFFSITE 0 0 0
> METADATA
> 'wms_title'    'ecw_tileindex_layer'
> 'wms_srs' 'EPSG:4326 EPSG:3587'
> END
> PROJECTION
> 'init=epsg:4326'
> END
> END
> ```

**Edit**

Here comes the whole procedure for making a WMS layer from a bunch of images.

1. Acquire some images. I use the demo images which come with Geoserver installation and files can be found from directory geoserver-2.5\data_dir\coverages\mosaic_sample. They are png images but it is not important because all the images behave in the same way for Mapserver if it has a driver for reading them.
2. Check the native projection of the images. In this case it can be done by opening one .prj file which shows "AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]". Gdalinfo is the standard tool for checking the projection but it fails with these png images.
3. Create tileindex as

   > C:\ms4w\apps\image_data>gdaltindex -write_absolute_path png_mosaic.shp
   >   *.png
4. Check the extents of the tileindex with ogrinfo

   > ```
   >  C:\ms4w\apps\image_data>ogrinfo -al -so png_mosaic.shp INFO: Open of
   >  `png_mosaic.shp'
   >        using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
   >
   >  Layer name: png_mosaic Geometry: Polygon Feature Count: 25 Extent:
   >  (6.346175, 36.491772) - (20.829683, 46.590767)
   > ```
5. Write a basic mapfile "tileindex.map" with all this information.

> ```
> MAP
> SIZE 800 800
> EXTENT 6.346175 36.491772 20.829683 46.590767
> UNITS DD
> IMAGECOLOR 20 250 250
> WEB
>     METADATA
>         "ows_enable_request" "*"
>         "wms_bbox_extended" "true"
>         "wms_srs" "CRS:84 EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
>         "wms_title" "tileindex demo"
>     END #metadata
> END #web    
> CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/ms4w/proj/nad"
> CONFIG "CPL_DEBUG" "ON"
> CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "c:/ms4w/tmp/debug.txt"
> PROJECTION
> "init=epsg:4326"
> END
>
> LAYER
> NAME "tileindex_layer"
> TYPE RASTER
> TILEINDEX "c:/ms4w/apps/image_data/png_mosaic"
> STATUS ON
> DEBUG 10
> PROJECTION
>         "init=epsg:4326"
> END
> METADATA
> "wms_title" "tileindex_layer"
> END
> END
> END
> ```
>
> 6. Test your Mapserver and mapfile. All these can be sent from the browser. The request and output that shows that everything is OK follows. See \comments

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe
No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.
```

\mapserv.exe executable is found

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tileindex.map
mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.
```

\mapfile from is found

```
http://localhost:8060/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tileindex.map&mode=map&layers=all
```

\mode=map may be ancient but sometimes handy for testing

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tileindex.map&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=409&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=tileindex_layer&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=6.34617,35.41501469437653,20.8297,47.667585305623476&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=
```

\this is a real complete WMS request and below is the result

[image: Mapserver WMS output from this tutorial]

Everything is done in a similar way with ECW images but it is better to test fist with some images which are for sure supported with all Mapserver and GDAL versions.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried that way, I use the shp2img to debug the map and it is ok. May be the problem is in the openlayers call? I call it wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('ortofotos','http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/prueba/mapa.map',{layers: 'ortofotos'},{isBaseLayer:true});

Comment: If shp2img works then I would test with some WMS client like OpenJUMP or QGIS next. You must help OpenJUMP by doing Zoom to WMS layer from the Table of contents because it does not zoom automatically. If WMS works you can be sure that the problem is in the OpenLayers configuration and ECW and Mapserver play no role at all.

Comment: I try with gvSig and it doesn't connect by wms. I don't know why but my mapfile is the next : 
MAP NAME mapa SIZE 1400 900 IMAGETYPE png IMAGECOLOR 196 240 255 EXTENT -16.1737 27.6847 -13.1254 29.4506 SHAPEPATH "C:/ms4w/apps/prueba/datos" WEB TEMPLATE "c:/ms4w/apps/prueba/index.html" IMAGEPATH "c:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/" IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/" METADATA WMS_TITLE "mapa" WMS_SRS "EPSG:4326 EPSG:4258" WMS_ONLINERESOURCE "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/prueba/mapa.map"    WMS_ENABLE_REQUEST "*" END END PROJECTION "init=EPSG:4258"
END UNITS meters and the code that you put.

Comment: Use your browser and send `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe` you should see "No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty." Next send `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/prueba/mapa.map` Do you see "mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided." If yes, everything is OK so far.

Comment: When I put the first URL I get the message "No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.", but when I put the second, I get "Content-type: text/html isValidTemplate(): Web application error. Missing magic string, c:/ms4w/apps/prueba/index.html doesn't look like a MapServer template." Is anything wrong?

Comment: Just as the error message says and Mapserver documentation too http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html "Templates must contain the magic string ‘mapserver template’ in the first line of the template". Please remember the rest of your life that never try to fix things in the final step as OpenLayers is in your case if the fundamentals are broken.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake, I didn't remmber that thing but I also have the same error, it doesn't load the files. I get the message msLoadMap(): Regular expression error. MS_DEFAULT_MAPFILE_PATTERN validation failed. msEvalRegex(): Regular expression error. String failed expression test.  I'm very new in mapserver sorry.

Comment: Well, you do not really need any templates for WMS. The latest error may mean that your mapfile does not start with magic word "MAP". Take a cup of coffee, relax, read carefully the document about setting up WMS with Mapserver http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html and you will for sure make it to work.

Comment: OK, after read the whole document and try to understand everything, I put my map in the right way. I get the message: "Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.". But I have the next error: "Internal server error 500" in all my requests. I don't know why my files doesn't load.

Comment: Great, you progress fine and Mapserver finds your mapfile. The URL you use should work now as WMS address for QGIS or OpenJUMP and other WMS clients. However the internal 500 error feels bad. You can make a quick test with native Mapserver request "mode=map&layers=all" like in here: http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/foss4g?mode=map&layers=all.

Comment: Thanks, I try what you say and when I put the URL: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/prueba/mapa.map&mode=map&layers=all" I get a image but I can't see the ecw files. I see the other layers but no the ecw layer. And the picture is cut at the bottom.

Comment: Great, now you know that your system runs mostly fine. Picture is cutted because the EXTENT you have set in your mapfile does not cover your data totally but that's not a big deal. You have DEBUG 5 for your ecw layer, what do you see in your MS_ERRORFILE?

Comment: I get a lot of : "[Mon Jun 23 16:35:14 2014].524000 msLoadMap(): 0.002s
[Mon Jun 23 16:35:36 2014].172000 msLoadMap(): 0.002s
[Mon Jun 23 16:38:52 2014].52000 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 026D8F68.
[Mon Jun 23 16:38:52 2014].84000 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 02718F10.
[Mon Jun 23 16:38:52 2014].235000 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 02828F68." What does it means?

Comment: If I load only the raster layer I get this:
[Mon Jun 23 17:07:14 2014].213000 msDrawRasterLayerLow(ortofotos): entering.
[Mon Jun 23 17:07:14 2014].214000 msDrawMap(): Layer 0 (ortofotos), 0.007s
[Mon Jun 23 17:07:14 2014].216000 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 02758EB8.

Comment: and then [Mon Jun 23 17:08:36 2014].324000 msWCSDispatch20(): wrong service (none)
[Mon Jun 23 17:08:36 2014].324000 msWCSParseRequest(): request is KVP.
[Mon Jun 23 17:08:36 2014].324000 msWCSDispatch(): SERVICE and REQUEST not included
[Mon Jun 23 17:08:36 2014].324000 mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.
[Mon Jun 23 17:08:36 2014].324000 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 026C88C8.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I don't know why, if I'm doing anything wrong but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in mapfile tif_mosaic instead of png_mosaic as tileindex file. I hope it was that. Otherwise it should work if you have ms4w in c:\ and demo images in c:\ms4w\apps\image_data and tileindex png_mosaic.shp also there.

Comment: I made some progress in this theme. I have no error now but I have blank image. I think is because the projection but I don't know how to fix it. I read that I need a world file but I don't know what is it and how to create or use it.

Comment: Ok, I have this 'msDrawRasterLayerLow(ortofoto): entering.' in my MS_ERROR.txt file. What does it means? It an error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: It only tells what is happening, not an error at all. I believe that you have trouble with projection, so no data in Your BBOX. Did you get my example to Work?

Comment: Yes, your example works fine. Now when I put the CONFIG "CPL_DEBUG" "ON" line, I get GDAL: Auto register C:\ms4w\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW when I test my map. I think it is work but I don't know if I have to change the ecw file to use another projection?

Comment: Gdalinfo tool should report the projection of the ecw images.

Comment: When I do gdalinfo to the ecw file I get 
C:\ms4w\apps\prueba\datos>gdalinfo PNOA_MA_OF_REGC95_HU28_h50_1079.ecw
Driver: ECW/ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
Files: PNOA_MA_OF_REGC95_HU28_h50_1079.ecw
Size is 130800, 75920
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (622830.000000000000000,3255270.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  622830.000, 3255270.000)
Lower Left  (  622830.000, 3236290.000)
Upper Right (  655530.000, 3255270.000)
Lower Right (  655530.000, 3236290.000)
Center      (  639180.000, 3245780.000)

Comment: I wondering if I have to add some coordinate system to the ecw file. I tried to use gdal_translate to conver to a .tif and then gdal_translate -a_srs WGS84 but this tif doesn't draw either.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the native projection of your source Images? Can you ask the EPSG code from the image provider?

Comment: It seems like the 2 files have the same projection but when I open in a desktop gis, the extents are different. One of them have -16.1737 27.6847 -13.1254 29.4506 and the other 259597 2,97938e+06..... What's the problem? I use EPSG:4326.

Comment: The first image is probably in EPSG:4326 and the extents are in degrees lon/lat but the second one for sure is not EPSG:4326 because the extents of the image are clearly in meteres. Those images cannot be used in a same Mapserver layer through a tileindex with your level of expertise. Find out the EPSG code of the latter image and reproject it into EPSG:4326 with gdalwarp, then build a new tileindex.

Comment: I fix it!!!!!!! I only have to change the projection to EPSG:4083 and it works. I can see the raster layer. Thx user30184